# Just get one row from PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I tried to find a way to just get a row using PHPExcel. After numerous searches on the internet, I only found a way to iterate over them, with an optional start row. This lead to the following solution:

```
foreach ($this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator($rownumber) as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo $cell->getValue();
    }

    break;
}
```

but this feels a little ugly. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes!

```
$row = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator($rownumber)->current();

$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo $cell->getValue();
}
```

I don't remember if you are supposed to use `next` or `current`.  If you are getting the wrong row, use `current()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be in that direction, just never knew about the methods used to cycle in `foreach`.

Comment: PHPExcel's Row and Cell Iterator both implement the standard PHP [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface; so all standard Iterator methods - current(), key(), next(), rewind() and valid() - are available. Additionally, they also implement seek(), prev() and resetStart() methods, the latter being useful if you instantiated the iterator with a row or column value other than the first row or column

Comment: does ther a possible to get an array directly instead of iterator

Answer (score 13):

```
$myRow = 123;

$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->rangeToArray(
        'A' . $myRow . 
        ':' . 
        $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() . $myRow
    );
```

will return the specified row as an array of cells